# Splat (*) operator offense with constant and attr_reader with rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop, linter

Am getting an ambiguous splat operator error while trying to assign attribute reader using a class constant.

```
Class X1
  CONST = [:a, :b, :c]
  attr_reader *CONST
end
```

However, I have tried a few work arounds which still lead to an rubocop offense/syntax error. Here are few of the approaches tried:

```
Class X1
  CONST = [:a, :b, :c]
  attr_reader(*CONST)
end


Class X1
  CONST = [:a, :b, :c]
  attr_reader(*(CONST))
end
```

Comment: `class` instead of `Class`

Comment: `attr_reader(*CONST)` does not offend Rubocop.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine and Rubocop doesn't find anything to complain (except for the lack of documentation on `X1`):

```
class X1
  CONST = %i[a b c].freeze
  attr_reader(*CONST)
end

x = X1.new
p x.a
# nil
p x.b
# nil
p x.c
# nil
```

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks. Some guidelines seem pretty arbitrary to me.

Comment: Yea, Change from `%i()` to `%i[]` seem to be taken from nowhere, so we disabled this one, because this change brings nothing and would just mess up git diff/blame history.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: From the [ruby-style-guidelines](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) : "[] for array literals(%w, %i, %W, %I) as it is aligned with the standard array literals."  You're right, it doesn't seem worth modifying the repo.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that a construct like:

```
attr_reader *FOO
```

should not be considered ambiguous, because the return of `attr_reader` happens in a void context, and thus performing a multiplication would be meaningless and likely a mistake.

Furthermore, idiomatic Ruby calls for macro methods to be invoked without parentheses, and the need for adding parentheses in *some cases* conflicts with this convention.

We're aware of this, and I have an  [open issue](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/4294) for this in the RuboCop repo. However, this cop is a bit special, since it is essentially just a wrapper around the diagnostics of the `parser` gem. There might not exist any easy way to make this exception without re-implementing the cop.

---

For now, you have a number of options to get around this:

- Use parentheses for macro methods with splat arguments.
- Inline disable the cop for each instance of this offense using the `rubocop:disable` directive. (This may or may not be feasible, depending on the number of offenses.)
- Disable this cop altogether, until the issue is resolved.